# Angular translate: placeholder not showing special characters correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding, utf-8, angular-translate

I am currently using angular-translate for a project, and it's going really well. However I run into a problem and I can't see why it's not working. I have an input field with a placeholder text, which has to be translated. This works fine, except when the translation-text includes special characters such as øæåüöä and so on.

This is my code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.query" autofocus translate-attr-placeholder="SEARCHPLACEHOLDER" translate />
<div translate>SEARCHPLACEHOLDER</div>
```

when set to english it outputs:

```
<input placeholder="Search for magazines" (rest omitted)>
<div class="ng-scope" translate="">Search for magazines</div>
```

however when i set it to danish it outputs:

```
<input placeholder="S&#248;g i indholdet af magasiner..." (rest omitted)>
<div class="ng-scope" translate="">Søg i indholdet af magasiner...</div>
```

As you can see, angular translates the text in the <div> correctly, but it outputs escaped characters in the input-element.

```
søg
```

becomes

```
s&#248;g
```

I couldn't find anything in the API. What am I missing?

Comment: I just solved it be removing my sanetizing strategy: `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);`
This however, seems like a bad solution. Also i don't understand why attributes and content would be sanitized differently?

Comment: Thank for the tip. It worked for me too. Has been found another solution?

Comment: Sadly not. I will update the question when I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To display the special character, use `$sce` (Strict Contextual Escaping)

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uPw2U/216/)

Hope it works :)