# Export to csv/pdf using ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm just using angular ui-grid.From there tutorial i'm able to export the grid data to csv/pdf but when the grid contains unicode characters it just gives ??? or some symbols.
Is there a way to export grid containig unicode characters using ui-grid?[image][image]

Comment: try to use $sce (Strict Contextual Escaping) for special characters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442680/angular-translate-placeholder-not-showing-special-characters-correctly/32443211#32443211

Comment: as you see there is no problem in rendering it's just don't take unicode charaters at the time of exporting